# interesting boundary problem of PDE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following PDE
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{\sigma^2 S^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial S^2} + rS\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} -rV = 0
\end{equation}
 with boundary condition 
\begin{equation}
V(S,T)=f(S)
\end{equation} where $V(S,t)$ is the solution to the PDE above.

Let $ρ(S,t)=\frac{∂V}{∂r}(S,t)$, then it can be shown that $\rho$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\frac{∂ρ}{∂t} + \frac{σ^2 S^2}{2}\frac{∂^2ρ}{∂S^2} + rS\frac{∂ρ}{∂S} −rρ=V−S\frac{∂V}{∂S}\end{equation}
 with boundary condition 
\begin{equation} \rho(S,T)=0. \end{equation}

${\it QUESTION}$: given that the PDE above uniquely determines $ρ$ , and assuming that both $V$  and $S\frac{∂V}{∂S}$   are of the order $o(1/(T−t))$  as $t→T^−$ , is it possible to show that
\begin{equation}
ρ(S,t)=(T−t)\Big(S\frac{∂V}{∂S}(S,t) −V(s,t)\Big).
\end{equation}

Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 1):

I give a derivation of the result from scratch below. However, this is long and technical. A much more simple way to proceed if we already know that the boundary condition for $\rho$ reads $\rho(S,T) = 0$, as we do here, and don't care about deriving it is to just substitute $\rho = (T-t)\rho_0$ where $\rho_0 = \left(S\frac{dV}{dS}-V\right)$ into the equation for $\rho$ to get

$$(T-t)\left(\frac{d\rho_0}{dt} + \frac{\sigma^2S^2}{2}\frac{d^2\rho_0}{dS^2} + rS \frac{d\rho_0}{dS} - r\rho_0\right) = 0$$

Now if $V$ is a solution to the original equation then one can show that $S\frac{dV}{dS}$ is also a solution and since the equation is linear so is any linear combination of these two solutions and the claim follows.

---

We will derive a formal integral-solution to the equation and use this to derive the desired result from scratch. Starting with

$$\frac{dV}{dt} + \frac{\sigma^2 S^2}{2}\frac{d^2 V}{dS^2} + rS \frac{dV}{dS} - rV = 0$$

we define $x=\log S$ to get it on a simpler form

$$\frac{dV}{dt} + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\frac{d^2 V}{dx^2} + \left(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right) \frac{dV}{dx} - rV = 0$$

We can now simplify the equation above by taking the Fourier transform w.r.t. $S$ giving us

$$\frac{d\hat{V}}{dt} = \hat{V}\left(\frac{\sigma^2\omega^2}{2} - i\omega\left(r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right) + r\right)$$

The solution of this ODE reads

$$\hat{V} = A(\omega) e^{\left(\frac{\sigma^2\omega^2}{2} - i\omega\left(r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right) + r\right)t}$$

Applying the boundary condition to determine $A$ and taking the inverse Fourier transform gives us an expression for the solution

$$V(S,t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\omega) e^{\left(\frac{\sigma^2\omega^2}{2} - i\omega\left(r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right) + r\right)(t-T) + i\omega \log S}d\omega$$

where $\hat{f}(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(S) = V(S,T)$. With the solution in hand we can go ahead and calculate the quantities we are interested in:

$$\rho(S,t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\omega)(t-T)(1-i\omega) e^{\left(\frac{\sigma^2\omega^2}{2} - i\omega\left(r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right) + r\right)(t-T) + i\omega \log S}d\omega$$

$$S\frac{dV(S,t)}{dS} - V(S,t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\omega)(-1 + i\omega) e^{\left(\frac{\sigma^2\omega^2}{2} - i\omega\left(r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right) + r\right)(t-T) + i\omega \log S}d\omega$$

and it follows that

$$\rho(S,t) = (T-t)\left(S\frac{dV}{dS} - V\right)$$

Comment: That is absolutely amazing. Thank you very much Winther. However, I have been told that there exists a solution without taking Fourier transform. Any ideas where the trick could be?

Comment: @Ruth90 Take $\rho = (T-t)\rho_0$ where $\rho_0 = SdV/dS - V$ then insert this into the equation for $\rho$ to find $(T-t)\left(\frac{d\rho_0}{dt} + \frac{\sigma^2S^2}{2}\frac{d^2\rho_0}{dS^2} + rS\frac{d\rho_0}{dS} - r\rho_0\right) = 0$. Now the term in the brackets is just the original equation and $\rho_0$ satisfy this since its the sum of $S\frac{dV}{dS}$ and $V$ which satisfy it independently. This is enough to prove the statement.

Comment: thank you. So basically, if I continue and divide your last equation through by $(T-t)$ I will show that $\rho_0$ satisfy the same PDE as $V$. But why is it a sufficient condition to prove that $\rho(S,t)=(T-t)\Bigg(S\frac{dV}{dS}-V\Bigg)\qquad$?

Comment: Isn't this what you want to prove? You ask: "is it possible to show that $\rho = (T-t)\ldots$ ?" If you start with a PDE for $\rho$ and then you want to show that the solution is given by the expression $\rho = (T-t)\ldots$) then all you have to do is to show that the expression $\rho = (T-t)\ldots$ satisfy the PDE and that it has the correct boundary condition. If you manage to do this then you have proven that $\rho = (T-t)\ldots$!

Comment: I do understand what you are saying. I am just confused that we start with $\rho=(T-t)...$ and by putting it in the PDE for $\rho$ obtain PDE for $V$.